# I can't find my soundcard using lspci; does that mean it's not linux's fault?

Tags: debian, audio

Pretty straightforward question, and [according to this diagram](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/images/tshoot_script.svg) it would seem the answer is *yes*.

My previous sound card stopped working (ie. stopped appearing when I ran `lspci`) so I bought a 2nd hand `Audigy 2 zs`, thinking the old sound card had died.

However, I'm having the same problem with this sound card. I've followed the usual steps of disabling on board sound and reinstalling `alsa` (although I'm thinking that `alsa` probably has nothing to do with this issue).

So since I've now had 2 soundcards not showing up when I run `lspci`, is it time to consider getting a new motherboard, or could this still be just a linux thing?

I'm using `Debian jessie`, although the issue did not start when I upgraded.

Comment: please put output of your lspci

Comment: I think PCI is pretty straightforward: if it's connected, it's listed. The PCI slot could be defective (a speck of dust in the wrong place is fixable in principle, a scratch not so much).

Comment: To rule out a OS / software problem, boot from a Live DVD. To rule out a problem with the PCI slot, try to put the card into another slot.

Comment: @Jan, I'll try that and post back. A friend of mine has a windows box so I'll try putting the card into his PC as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a hardware issue. I opened up my box, took out the card, put it back in, restarted, and *voila!* It was back...